# How to detect if a player has a Lime Carpet named "$5"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm working on a map, and at one part of it, you have to have a Lime Green Carpet in your inventory (I know the data for that is 14), and then it takes it and removes some blocks using `/fill`. I was using this:

```
/testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:<minecraft:carpet>,Damage:<14>s}]}
```

I got that off another question, but it has to be named: $5

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm no command expert, so I need some help.

Comment: Things like solved or answered don't belong in questions; we strive to ensure that questions can help more than just the asker, and who knows?  Someone might come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do into the chat

```
/scoreboard objectives add Money dummy
```

Then in a repeating command block have

```
/scoreboard players set @a Money 0
```

Then in a chain command block do this command

```
/scoreboard players set @a Money 1 {SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"$5"}}}}
```

And in another chain command block

```
/execute @a[score_Money_min=1] ~ ~ ~ YOURCOMMANDHERE
```

And that is how you do it.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I decided to stop work on that map but I needed that for my new map. I'll try that, thanks!